# lenovo C340 - how to install remote control driver for ubuntu

Tags: drivers, lenovo

Hello guys I have computer all-in-one **lenovo C340** like [lenovo](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops/essential/c-series/c340/). I had Windows 10 installed, now I finally installed ubuntu 16.04 on my computer. But I a have not found a driver for ubuntu. Do someone knows how to install drivers so that my remote control can work in ubuntu ?

Comment: What remote control?

Answer (score 0):

There are no official Ubuntu driver releases for this product (I have only found drivers for Windows on lenovo's website). So my advice is to reinstall windows, or try to find ubuntu drivers for your remote. But I doubt, that any would exist.